# spring-smb-integration error after move to java 17

Tags: spring, java-17, smb

I had an application that was using spring-integration-smb.
I have now updated this application to java17 and the latest version of spring-integration-smb and are now getting a bouncy castle error.

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/DERApplicationSpecific\
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue.